# Override templated method from library with my own implementation

Tags: c++, qt, templates, googletest

Google test declares a templated method `PrintTo`:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os);
```

There are several overloads without template. I also added overloads for my custom types.

My problem is that I dont like the default templated method provided by google and instead I would like to implement it like this:

```
template<typename T>
void PrintTo(const T &val, ::std::ostream *os)
{
    QString str;
    QDebug(&str) << val;
    *os << qUtf8Printable(str);
}
```

This would solve the problem for many Qt types. I cannot change the implemention inside google tests code. I need to reimplement it in my own code.

Using my template method I get this compiler error:

```
include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:707:22: error: call of overloaded ‘PrintTo(const QChar&, std::ostream*&)’ is ambiguous
     PrintTo(value, os);
                      ^
include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:707:22: note: candidates are:
include/gtest/gtest-printers.h:454:6: note: void testing::internal::PrintTo(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = QChar; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]
 void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os) {
      ^
In file included from tstgoogletest.cpp:51:0:
googletestqttypes.h:24:6: note: void PrintTo(const T&, std::ostream*) [with T = QChar; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]
 void PrintTo(const T &val, ::std::ostream *os)
      ^
```

Is it possible to "overload" the templated method with my custom implementation without listing every type I want to use?

QDebug already supports thousands of types and I dont want to miss that feature!

Comment: Both template functions have the same signature and same template argument - therefore compiler cannot distinguish them. What if you declare your function like: `template<typename C> void PrintTo(const C &val, ::std::ostream *os) {...}`?

Comment: I dont think changing the argument name would change anything! The compiler error output also looks the same.

Comment: `void PrintTo(const QAVariant& value, ::std::ostream* os);` Might capture some of the types that you are looking for through implicit conversion, otherwise you probably will have to write a separate function for each type.

Comment: I tried implementing it using QVariant but without success. Now the default implementation by google is being used all the time!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler cannot perform the overload as your function signature is exactly the same as that of google. You could create a new type to force the overload e.g:

```
#include <iostream>

// Google version
template <class T> 
void print(const T& value, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "Google print: " << value << std::endl;
}

// My wrapper type

template <class T>
struct PrintWrap {
    const T& value_;

    PrintWrap(const T& value): value_(value){}
};

template <class T>
PrintWrap<T> printWrap(const T& value) {
    return PrintWrap<T>(value);
}


template <class T>
void print(const PrintWrap<T>& printWrap, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "My special print: " << printWrap.value_ << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string value = "Hallo world";
  print(printWrap(value), std::cout);   

  // your code goes here
  return 0;
}
```

In the event of you not having control over the calling code, you could overload the necessary functions required in printWrap e.g operator == is overloaded below, as the library function (checkEqualTo) requires this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Google version
template <class T> 
void print(const T& value, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "Google print: " << value << std::endl;
}

// My wrapper type 
// :NOTE Overload what is required by Google, in this
// case lets assume operator== as example
template <class T>
struct PrintWrap {
    const T& value_;
    PrintWrap(const T& value): value_(value){}

  friend bool operator==(const PrintWrap& lhs, const PrintWrap& rhs) {
   return lhs.value_ == rhs.value_;
  }
};

template <class T>
PrintWrap<T> printWrap(const T& value) {
    return PrintWrap<T>(value);
}


template <class T>
void print(const PrintWrap<T>& printWrap, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "My special print: " << printWrap.value_ << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
bool checkEqualTo(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  if (lhs == rhs) return true;
  print(lhs, std::cout);
  print(rhs, std::cout);
  return false;
}

// Google code...
#define CHECK_EQUAL(x,y) checkEqualTo(x,y)

int main() {
  std::string value = "Hallo world";
  CHECK_EQUAL(printWrap(value), printWrap(value));

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also have a look at this [guide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#teaching-google-test-how-to-print-your-values), which is GTest's documentation concerning print customization, which involves defining PrintTo in the same namespace as the type in question in order to use ADL(Argument Dependent Lookup).

Below is an example of using ADL for this purpose, which is what they envisaged as mechanism for extension, it would seam:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

// Google version template <class T>  
void print(const T& value, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "Google print: " << value << std::endl; 
}

namespace custom {

template <class T>
struct Printable : T
{
  template <class...Args>
  Printable(Args&&... args) 
  : T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  { }
};

template <class T>
void print(const Printable<T>& value, std::ostream& os) {
  os << "My special print: " << value << std::endl;
}

} //custom

int main() {
  custom::Printable<std::string> x = "my string";
  custom::Printable<std::string> y = "my other string";

  assert(! (x == y));

  //found by ADL      
  print(x, std::cout); 
  return 0;
}
```

Here above, the function declaration in the same namespace as the argument has lookup precedence, and therefore the ambiguity doesn't exist. You don't need to use Printable (there is perhaps a better complete implementation). You could have a print per type as necessary.

Note that the code above is my example. GTest requires the overload to be:

```
void PrintTo(const Bar& bar, ::std::ostream* os)...
```

In addition, you could just overload operator << for your type, as mentioned in their documentation.

Comment: I dont call `PrintTo` myself. This is part of the testing framework. I place a macro like `ASSERT_EQ(left, right)` and somewhere deep in google's code will be a call to `PrintTo` using `left` or `right`.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way to solve this? I dont want to write these wrap methods in every test. We already have hundrets of tests and I dont want to change them all. EDIT: I think I answered to a deleted comment...

Comment: I've modified my example to show how you can overcome the ASSERT_EQ problem